# How can I create a conditional where clause in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

Table A pulls back rows in table B. If col2 of table B is 'XYZ' then I only want rows containing XYZ for that id.

```
Table A   Table B
id bid    bid  col2  
1  2      2    ABC
1  3      3    ABC
2  4      4    ABC
2  5      5    XYZ
```

The output should have 3 rows total, two rows for id 1 and 1 row for id 2.

This what I have tried so far

```
select * from table a, table b
where a.col1 = b.col1
and if 'ABC' in (select b1.col2 from table b1 where b1.col1 = b.col1)  then b.col2 = 'ABC' end
and if 'XYZ' in (select b1.col2 from table b1 where b1.col1 = b.col1)  then b.col2 = 'XYZ' end
```

I have also tried

```
and case when (select count(b1.col) from table b1 where b1.col = b.col1 and b1.col = 'XYZ') >0 then b.col1 = 'XYZ' end
```

Exact code

```
select *
from scores a, queues b 
where res_id = '112321'
and b.que_id = a.que_id
and case when (select count(qasgn_cd) from queues where que_id = b.que_id and QASGN_CD = 'BTQFR') >0 then b.que_id = '1' else FALSE end
```

Gives an error ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Add an `else` clause to your case/if with `false` value . eg: `case when x then y else FALSE end` - if it returns false, the row will be discarded from the result

Comment: It says that I'm missing a key word, if I put false in the else statement it gives an invalid error

Comment: Update your question with exact code and returned error message

Comment: Could you explain this: `select b.col2 from table b1 where b1.col = b.col1` - Does `b.col2` come from B table or B1 table ? Why do you select b.col2 column from b1 table ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following with your `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from scores a, queues b 
where res_id = '112321'
and b.que_id = a.que_id
and case when (select count(qasgn_cd)
               from queues 
               where que_id = b.que_id 
               and QASGN_CD = 'BTQFR') > 0 
    then TRUE
    else FALSE
    end
```

Comment: This give an ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are as followed:

```
create table "Table A" (   
   id  number, 
   bid number
);

insert into "Table A" values (1,  2);
insert into "Table A" values (1,  3);
insert into "Table A" values (2,  4);    
insert into "Table A" values (2,  5);    


create table "Table B" (   
   bid  number, 
   col2 varchar2(50)
);

insert into "Table B" values (2,    'ABC');
insert into "Table B" values (3,    'ABC');
insert into "Table B" values (4,    'ABC');
insert into "Table B" values (5,    'XYZ');
```

You can partition your data by ID and distinguish between partition containing 'XYZ' and those which do not. In the outer select you can simply filter your result.

```
select * 
  from (select a.*,
               b.col2,
               count(case when b.COL2 = 'XYZ' then 1 else null end) over (partition by a.ID) as cnt
          from "Table A" a
          join "Table B" b on b.BID = a.BID) t
 where (t.cnt = 0)
    or (t.cnt = 1 and t.col2 = 'XYZ');
```

You can use "case when..." also in the where clause but in this case it is not neccessary.

```
select * 
  from (select a.*,
               b.col2,
               count(case when b.COL2 = 'XYZ' then 1 else null end) over (partition by a.ID) as cnt
          from "Table A" a
          join "Table B" b on b.BID = a.BID) t
 where case 
          when (t.cnt = 0) 
            or (t.cnt = 1 and t.col2 = 'XYZ') then 1 
          else NULL 
       end = 1;
```